# .NET converting file to image to store in a database

Tags: asp.net, .net

Does anyone know of a way in .NET to take an incoming stream of a file and convert it to an image to be stored in the database? (Not sure if this is possible, but wanted to check).

Edit: it is not necessarily an image stream

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the stream into a `byte[]`, then save that into the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the image stream to byte array and store in binary or varbinary data type in database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of transferring the image into a byte array in C#:

```
private static byte[] ReadImage(string p_postedImageFileName, string[] p_fileType)
{
    bool isValidFileType = false;
    try
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(p_postedImageFileName);

        foreach (string strExtensionType in p_fileType)
        {
            if (strExtensionType == file.Extension)
            {
                isValidFileType = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidFileType)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(p_postedImageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

            br.Close();

            fs.Close();

            return image;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

#endregion
```